# Get borders to head rows and head columns with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a system (maybe you guessed it from the snippet, it's confluence) and try to style tables.

**Important**
I have no chance to modify the **table-html** output, I can only add some CSS styles. The tables can occur in every combination on a page and are added by users.

This is the structure and possible table comibnations - *this is only an example* - there are other combinations.

```css
.confluenceTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.confluenceTh, .confluenceTd {
 padding: 6px 8px;
 border: 1px solid #888a85;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: none;
}

table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTh, 
table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTd {
 border-top: none;
}

.confluenceTh:first-child, .confluenceTd:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}



table.confluenceTable thead tr:first-child .confluenceTh {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CC0018;
}

table.confluenceTable tr .confluenceTh + :not(.confluenceTh) {
  border-left: 2px solid #CC0018; 
}
```

```html
<h2>First</h2>
<p>table without headers</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>table with column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Third</h2>
<p>table with row header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Fourth</h2>
<p>table with row and column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- This element should also have a border right -->
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The Problem is the **Fourth** table - I found no way to add a `border-right` to `1.1`, which is column and row header. *Does anyone see a pure CSS solution?*

In a future step, there might also be headers in the middle of a table...

Comment: It is impossible to solve this using pure CSS. You want to detect if there is a `th` in a `tr` in the table body and depending on that, change the style of a column in the table head. However, CSS only supports selectors that go down the DOM tree, never up (to parent elements), which is what you would need. You need a class on the table (head), which you could add via JavaScript.

Comment: @Justastudent thanks, maybe this was the reason I didn't find a solution - because there is none. You may post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just did. Sorry for the late reply, I wanted to take the time to write up a decent answer for you :-)

Comment: @Justastudent no problem, your comment was an answer already, so I didn't invest further time to find a CSS solution. I also used JS now, but it's frustrating for such a "simple" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem, more generally**
You have the following structure in your HTML.

```
element.A1
  element.A2
element.B1
  element.B2
```

Now, you want to style `A2` depending on some properties `B2` has. For example, if `B2` is present, if `B2` is a specific type of element (like a `div` or `span`), if it has a certain [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (`[data-foo="bar"]`), et cetera.

**Solving using CSS**
Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to do this using a pure CSS solution. This is because all selectors in CSS go from an element to any descendant of that element, but never the other way around. For example, `a b` selects all elements of type `b` that are a descendant of `a`. With `a > b`, only children of `a` type elements are considered. [There is however no way to go the other way.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/962603)

**Solving using JS + CSS**
For now, you can solve your problem by using a certain class and applying that class using JavaScript. Something along the lines of the following.

```css
.A1.special .A2 {
    /* special styling on A2 */
}
```

```js
var b2s = document.querySelectorAll('.B2'), i;
for (i = 0; i < b2s.length; ++i) {
    if (isSpecial(b2s[i])) {
        b2s[i].parentNode.previousSibling.classList.add('special');
    }
}
```

References: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

The `isSpecial` function would check for whatever properties you would want to check for. In particular, I implemented your specific question in the following snippet.

```js
// detect special case and add class for CSS styling
var firstRows = document.querySelectorAll('.confluenceTable tbody > tr:first-child'), i;
for (i = 0; i < firstRows.length; ++i) {
  if (firstRows[i].querySelector('th') !== null) {
    firstRows[i].parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('special');
  }
}
```

```css
.confluenceTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.confluenceTh, .confluenceTd {
 padding: 6px 8px;
 border: 1px solid #888a85;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: none;
}

table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTh, 
table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTd {
 border-top: none;
}

.confluenceTh:first-child, .confluenceTd:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}

table.confluenceTable thead tr:first-child .confluenceTh {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CC0018;
}

table.confluenceTable tr .confluenceTh + :not(.confluenceTh) {
  border-left: 2px solid #CC0018; 
}

/* add styling for the exceptional case */
table.confluenceTable.special > thead > tr > th:first-child{
  border-right:2px solid #CC0018;
}
```

```html
<h2>First</h2>
<p>table without headers</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>table with column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Third</h2>
<p>table with row header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Fourth</h2>
<p>table with row and column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- This element should also have a border right -->
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `nth-of-type` pseudo selector as below to select `4th table` and add `border to right-side` of `th first-child`.

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document
>   tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent
>   element.

```
table.confluenceTable:nth-of-type(4) > thead > tr > th:first-child{
  border-right:2px solid #CC0018;
}
```

```css
.confluenceTable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.confluenceTh, .confluenceTd {
 padding: 6px 8px;
 border: 1px solid #888a85;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: none;
}

table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTh, 
table.confluenceTable tr:first-child .confluenceTd {
 border-top: none;
}

.confluenceTh:first-child, .confluenceTd:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}



table.confluenceTable thead tr:first-child .confluenceTh {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CC0018;
}

table.confluenceTable tr .confluenceTh + :not(.confluenceTh) {
  border-left: 2px solid #CC0018; 
}
table.confluenceTable:nth-of-type(4) > thead > tr > th:first-child{
  border-right:2px solid #CC0018; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<h2>First</h2>
<p>table without headers</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>table with column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">1.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Third</h2>
<p>table with row header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.1</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Fourth</h2>
<p>table with row and column header</p>
<table class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- This element should also have a border right -->
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">2.1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">3.1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.2</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.2</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh">1.3</th>
      <td class="confluenceTd">2.3</td>
      <td class="confluenceTd">3.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for this particular example. The problem is, I am looking for a gerneric solution.

Comment: @ppasler Okay, so your code contains many tables, so using nth-of-type you can select particular table and style.

Comment: This is for a wiki system so the user input what they want. text, images, whatever and tables. There can be many tables which can have several row and column headers.

Comment: Okay @ppasler then you need to come-up some unique idea, what I mean is at-present there are just four tables, first doesn't got any style whereas 2nd,3rd and 4th as, so could assign different class to them and apply same style every-time when this type of table layout are found.

Comment: That is exactly my problem, I can't modify the html of a table, although I can change content of a table (it's a wysiwyg editor). I really appreciate your effort, but it's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137229/discussion-between-frnt-and-ppasler).

Answer (score 1):

Try this)

```
body > .confluenceTable:nth-child(12) thead tr:first-child th:first-child   {
    border-right: 2px solid #CC0018; 
}
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/wxfL4ocg/

Comment: Thanks, this works if I only have these fixed tables, but I need a generic solution for user input.